# Install Bootstrap 5 on Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, laravel-7

I can't install bootstrap 5 in laravel 7 scaffolding, I found many guides online but they all don't work. I am using Laravel 7 installed with composer and Laravel 7 has bootstrap 4 as standard. Can anyone help me?

I follow this steps

```
composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui bootstrap

npm install && npm run dev
```

After I modify in resources/js/bootstrap.js

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.Popper = require('@popperjs/core');
    window.bootstrap = require('bootstrap');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

My package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.15.2",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
```

Seems all is installed but when I import component like dropdowns, and more, doesn't work. I added the bootstrap include in .scss file, and script in the head of the page and css file too.

This is my app.js

```
  /**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

This is my app.scss

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the steps you have taken to get rid of BS4 and install BS5. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Did you recompile your assets using `npm run dev` or `npm run watch` after making changes to `bootstrap.js` and the `.scss` file?

Comment: yes i do `npm run dev` after i modify `bootstrap.js`

Comment: Any errors/file not found's in your browser's DevConsole/Network tab when calling your page? Can you post the code you use to include the `app.js` and `app.css`? Usually, `app.css` goes into the head, scripts should be loaded at the end of the page, right before `</body>`

Comment: No error in console